# Circular integration Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-2.7

I need to calculate this integral in Python:

[image]

where
Etax and rho are arrays calculated at each position in s which is an array representing every point in a circle.
My question  is how to calculate  ds here and evaluate theintegral?

Comment: ds = circumference of circle / number of points.

Comment: @Thomas How can i include it in the integration ? by multiplying this value to every parameter in the integrand array ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. An integral is just the limit of a sum, so you can approximate it by a sum.

Answer (score 0):

Dont worry about `ds`, in theory of real analysis it is just the infinitesimal arc length over the contour, instead you can use the module `sympy` allowing you to compute that kind of integral with the function `line_integral` having as parameters the integrand and a `sympy.Curve` instance.

Comment: Thank you, i have tried:
from sympy import Curve, line_integrate
line_integrate(A,s) 
But i gor an erre : line_integrate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'vars'"

Comment: Cuz there is a lacking of variables, if by example i have f(x,y) = x, and i have already defined my sympy.Curve  as Crv, then the correct call is line_integrate(x, Crv, [x,y]), assuming of course that x and y are defined symbols

Comment: But in my case i don't have the x and y variables i only have arrays of numbers

Comment: If the arrays are from the independents variables, then you can fit them on a region that can be passed to Curve function as parameter